# Unable to send '<' and '>' through URL

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, http

I am trying to send a String '' through an AJAX call to my server, which in turn inserts into the database. The string is sent as q request parameter using get method from the UI.

However, the process is not completed and the UI hangs. When I try to send the string 'ABCDEF'  it works fine and the string is inserted into the DB.

Could you please tell me why the problem with '<' and '>' and how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the values?

Comment: Probably use `encodeURIComponent` to wrap the string.

Comment: Can you use &gt; and &lt; for > and < resp

Comment: I do use encodeURIComponent in the javascript before sending the  string to my java code.

Comment: You have to encode your URL before hitting to Server.

Comment: @Danton : I do use URL encoding, so I believe &gt; or &lt; would not be required.

Comment: You can use this String urlToHit = "http://exa.com/query?input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");

Comment: Then you might logged the string to see what it contain before insert to database, maybe you need to escape the chars, not familiar with java, can't help more.

Comment: what about %3E for > and %3C for < ?

Comment: log the string after encoding and let's see what's wrong.

Comment: @iplus26 : After encoding, the string <ABCDEF> is converted to %3CABCDEF%3E

Comment: @Nishit and then you can log it on server side.

Comment: @iplus26 : On the server side it shows the string as <ABCDEF>

Comment: @Nishit so what's wrong...